# What is max number of valid modifiers you can have while declaring a class in c#?

Tags: c#, modifier

This question is more for curiosity.

By modifiers I mean, keywords that you add before declaring a class.

e.g.

```
//1       2        3             
public abstract partial class Foo
{

}
```

This have 3 modifiers `public`, `abstract`, and `partial`.

Zero modifiers, in this question perspective, would be something like

```
class Foo
{

}
```

What is the max number of valid modifiers you can have before the name of the class when declaring it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum number is...

## 5!

(or 6 if you count `unsafe`)

According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#class-declarations), a class declaration looks like this:

```
class_declaration
    : attributes? class_modifier* 'partial'? 'class' identifier type_parameter_list?
      class_base? type_parameter_constraints_clause* class_body ';'?
    ;
```

You probably don't count the attributes as "modifiers", but you probably *would* count the `partial` keyword as a "class modifier", though it is not an actual `class_modifier`.

The list of `class_modifier` is:

```
class_modifier
    : 'new'
    | 'public'
    | 'protected'
    | 'internal'
    | 'private'
    | 'abstract'
    | 'sealed'
    | 'static'
    | class_modifier_unsafe
    ;
```

We know the longest access modifier is `protected internal`, so we can ignore all the access modifiers:

```
class_modifier
    : 'new'
    | 'abstract'
    | 'sealed'
    | 'static'
    | class_modifier_unsafe
    ;
```

You can only choose one of `sealed`, `static` and `abstract`, so we are left with 6 "keywords":

- `protected`
- `internal`
- [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#the-new-modifier)
- `sealed`/`static`/`abstract`
- `partial`
- `unsafe`

Note that `new` and `protected internal` can only be used in nested class declarations.

Comment: No way, I can't believe it's `5!`, that is too much! (Math joke)